# Openssl RSA encryption-decryption

Tags: php, android, ios, openssl, rsa

I'm using RSA private-public key encryption to encrypt data coming from server. The main goal is to encrypt json data that server serves to iOS and android clients, so no other app can use this data. So what would be better choice? To encrypt data on server using private key and to decrypt in app with public key or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea would be to use two pairs.

- **Outgoing** data will be encrypted by **Server public**
- **Incoming** data will be encrypted by **Client public**

You can generate client key pairs on first run of application, and send your public to server encrypted by **server public**

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to keep in mind is that using any PSK encryption will require you to store at least one of these keys in the client.

However binaries of apps are easily examined and keys can be extracted, so this method can be circumvented.

Using SSL already does encrypt the data, so instead of double encrypting things using PSK, you may want to consider just using a passcode or a token based authentication mechanism to help restrict access.